# GitHub Actions: How to pass toJSON() result to shell commands

Tags: json, bash, yaml, github-actions, jsonparser

So, I'm working with Github Actions on end-to-end testing. The setup I'm looking at is having one job retrieve a list of urls to be tested, and my second job creates a matrix with that list and tests them all. My problem here is that when I actually run my testing script, it has to be done from the command line, because I'm using Playwright. Therefore I can't use my matrix object directly; I have to output it to a JSON file. The problem is that toJSON creates invalid pretty-printed JSON when I output it to my file, which breaks my script. Here's my code:

```yaml
name: <name>

on:
    push:
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    fetch_strategic_urls:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        outputs:
            urls: ${{ steps.req-urls.outputs.urls }}
        steps:
            - name: Request Urls
              id: req-urls
              run: |
                  export RESPONSE=$(
                    curl -X GET -H "Accept: application/json" <api-endpoint>)
                  echo "::set-output name=urls::$RESPONSE"
    run_tests:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        strategy:
            matrix:
                url: ${{needs.fetch_strategic_urls.outputs.urls}}
        needs: fetch_strategic_urls
        steps:
            - ...
            - ...
            - run: |
                  ls
                  echo '${{ toJSON(matrix.url) }}' >> props.json
                  cat props.json
                  npm test
              working-directory: E2E.Tests
```

No matter which configuration of `echo ${{matrix.url}} >> props.json` I've tried (`cat <<'EOF' > props.json ${{matrix.url}}`, adding and removing quotes), it always produced JSON files that have no quotes, i.e.: `{ url: string }` instead of `{"url": "string"}`, which is invalid. This is obviously pretty breaking behavior. I've seen a lot of people online recommending jq, but I don't see how I would use it in this case, since I doubt jq can parse a GitHub-type JSON object, which is necessary for me to use when sharding my jobs. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please don't just paste your entire YAML, but create a [minimal reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not easy to put a JSON doc directly in the command line. You can use env vars.

```yaml
- shell: bash
  env:
    JSON_DOC: ${{ toJSON(some.var) }}
  run: |
    printf '%s\n' "$JSON_DOC" > foo.json
    cat foo.json
    ...
```

Comment: This works best if you have a small json. Once JSON gets big, Github fails with `Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/runner/_work/repo/repo'. Argument list too long`

Comment: @ShinebayarG for big json doc you may use awk, python, ...

Answer (score 3):

Github actions documenation has a solution here:

```
name: Context testing
on: push

jobs:
  dump_contexts_to_log:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Dump GitHub context
        id: github_context_step
        run: echo '${{ toJSON(github) }}'
```

From https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log

Comment: this does not work if toJSON() result includes `'` chars.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, or even an attempt, more a place to post about a related GH actions oddity.

I thought I had the above solved with:

```
- name: step-name
  run: | # shell
    echo "${{ toJson(github) }}"
```

which, worked fine, until I merged to main, the default branch, at which point it generates this error:

```
##[debug]/usr/bin/bash -e /home/runner/work/_temp/11b0a2ad-c8d6-4251-8b4a-6ab18d3de45f.sh
/home/runner/work/_temp/11b0a2ad-c8d6-4251-8b4a-6ab18d3de45f.sh: line 58: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

Despite that offending statment ( `${{ toJson(github) }}` ) being no where near line 58.

Note that one can't even have this as a comment:

```
# echo ${{ toJson(github) }}
```

as that still fails the job, apparently with something in the `github` object, that is only present in the default branch.

All I can think of is that the returned string from `toJSON()` isn't always correctly escaped, so it is breaking the YAML parser's ability to extract a legal shell script from the action yaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use echo with single quotes:

```yaml
- name: Print inputs
  run: |
  echo 'Inputs: ${{ toJson(inputs) }}'
```