# how to list all the labels of a PR

Tags: github-actions

how can I output the array of labels associated to a PR. an echo gives me `Array` as a result:

```yaml
name: An action test
on:
    pull_request:
        branches: ['master']
jobs:
    generate-matrix:
        runs-on: [Linux]
        container: xxx
        steps:
            - name: test
              run: echo ${{ github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name }}
```

Comment: What is the issue with your current approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [toJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#tojson) function, like this:

```
name: An action test
on:
    pull_request:
        branches: ['master']
jobs:
    generate-matrix:
        runs-on: [Linux]
        container: xxx
        steps:
            - name: test
              run: echo "${{ toJSON(github.event.pull_request.labels.*.name) }}"
```

You should get a JSON array like this:

```
[
  label1,
  label2
]
```

If you want to use this array in a shell command, you can have a look to this post: [GitHub Actions: How to pass toJSON() result to shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72953526/github-actions-how-to-pass-tojson-result-to-shell-commands)